# C# Create double[][] from DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have a DataTable where every entry in every row and column is a double. I need to convert it to a two dimensional `double[][]` object. There are no column headers and the number of rows and columns can be different each time.

Is there Linq to simplify this? Can I apply `Math.Round()` for each value as I build my double[][] object?

Comment: You can do it with Linq but instead of giving you the full code you can probably work it out with the following. `DataTable.Rows` is a collection but it happen that you can do `myDatatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList()` to get a `List<DataRow>`. Now knowing that, you have to also know that `DataRow` has a property `ItemArray` which is the value of that row for each column as a convenient `object[]`. This should be plenty of hints for you to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `DataTable` with all columns that can be *converted* into `double` (i.e. columns can be of type `float`, `int` etc.) you can put something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

DataTable table = ...

double[][] array = table
  .Rows
  .OfType<DataRow>()
  .Select(dataRow => dataRow
    .ItemArray
    .Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item))
    .ToArray())
  .ToArray();
```

Sure, you can add some processing, say, `Math.Round` if required; add it after the inner `Select`:

```
   ...
   .Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item)) // from now on we have double
   .Select(value => Math.Round(value, 2))  // Let's round the values
   .ToArray())
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this approach that is efficient and safe:

```
DataColumn[] doubleColumns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(double))
    .ToArray();

double[][] result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => doubleColumns.Select(c => r.Field<double>(c)).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: It's good to mention that this only work if columns are actually really all double and not other type that someone would want to interpret as double for simplicity reasons like float, int..